# VBA Sort method of Range class failed

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, runtime-error

I know there are several threads on this topic but none of the answers have helped resolved this error.

I am trying to sort a table using three keys but receive the error, "Run-time error '1004': Sort method of Range class failed"

I've tried changing "Range("L2")" to ".Range("L2")" and received the error, "Compile error: Invalid or unqualified reference"

I've tried specifying the actual range instead of using columns, I've removed the last two keys and tried just the first, still received the run-time error.

```
shtData.Activate

shtData.Range(Range("A2"), Range("Z8000").End(xlUp)).Sort _
Key1:=Range("L2"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
Key2:=Range("M2"), Order2:=xlAscending, _
Key3:=Range("B2"), Order3:=xlAscending, _
Header:=xlYes
```

If you have any suggestions, I'd greatly appreciate it. I had this working yesterday and my excel crashed and did not recover the changes I made, I cannot figure out why I can't get it to work today.

Comment: Do you have headers in row 2?

Comment: @Rdster Yes, my headers are in row 2

Comment: You need to fully qualify the ranges, which can provide errors if you don't. I.e. `shtData.Range(shtData.Range("A2"), shtData.Range("Z8000").End(xlUp)).Sort`, and the same with your `Keys`.

Comment: @BruceWayne, but that `shtData.Activate` makes it already

Comment: @user3598756 understood, but it is best practice to [avoid using `.Activate`/`.Select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: The dot is a member access. There's the global-scope `Range` which implicitly refers to the active sheet, and then there's a worksheet's `.Range` property, which refers to a range *in that worksheet*. A `With` block gives you an object to qualify members with - of course using an unqualified `.Range` is a compile error.

Comment: @BruceWayne, sure! Just wanted to make it clear that couldn't raise the error experienced by OP. Unless Mat's comment says the opposite (I must read it carefully...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you most probably have no data in "Z" column

if data rows range can be safely sized by column "A" not empty cells then go like follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim shtData As Worksheet

    Set shtData = Worksheets("Data") '<--| some setting of 'shtData'
    With shtData
        .Range("Z2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Sort _
        Key1:=.Range("L2"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
        Key2:=.Range("M2"), Order2:=xlAscending, _
        Key3:=.Range("B2"), Order3:=xlAscending, _
        Header:=xlYes
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Good call using `With`

Comment: @user3598756 Thank you! I completely forgot I removed a column yesterday so my data ends at Y now.

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible you could end up changing amount of columns again in the future, you could do something like.

```
With shtData
Range(Range("A2"), Cells(Range("A8000").End(xlUp).Row, Range("ZZ2").End(xlLeft).Column)
```

That way it will automatically size the sort area for however many columns you are using as well as rows.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the advice. I am continually adjusting this data range to get my program to work so this will work much better.